# Do I need to resize UITableView while Pushing or popping navigation controller - IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Every one may think, why we need to resize table view when popping a view. I have a strange problem, I have a table view with Navigation bar showing, from that view I am pushing a new view which don't have navigation bar(i.e I'm hiding it), when I pop that new view, my table view height is reducing as it have navigation bar currently showing.

I took a long time to find this was the problem. Any one experienced like this, Do we need to resize our view size or controls in this case.

Please check the attached image, first one is normal...

[image]

second one is after popping from the new view which don't have navigation bar...

[image]

Last row got missed in section 1 because height of table view got reduced.

Comment: can you please attach the screen shots of it.

Comment: thanks for updating...reviewing it.

Comment: try to reload table in viewwillAppeare method.

Comment: I'm already doing, No luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.....Hope it will work.Set the UITableView layout to set to the full view. [image]

Comment: If I do that, than table view will come for whole view right?

Comment: No it will set to the view exactly how u set in ur xib everytime.Try this, but i am not sure.

Comment: I have adjusted, only horizontal size, I have removed the vertical resizing, now my table view height got fixed. Thanks for your idea.